# reset the kubectl context to docker desktop

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I have installed docker desktop on my windows 10 and have enabled Kubernetes. When I run the `kubectl config current-context` command I am getting this response `gke_k8s-demo-263903_asia-south1-a_kubia`. How do I set up the context to point to `docker-desktop`? I remember that I had worked with GKE earlier but not sure how to reset the context.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From your local machine run, you should see docker-desktop listed:

> kubectl config get-contexts

Then run the below:

> kubectl config use-context docker-desktop

If the cluster name you want to communicate with is not listed, it means you haven't got to context file to the cluster.

Comment: How do you set `docker-desktop` context as the default?

Answer (score 3):

One additional note: If you have accidentally deleted the `docker-desktop` context from your `~/.kube/config` you can re-create it when restarting the docker/Kubernetes Engine in the Docker-Desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any `docker-desktop` kubernetes context at all, you need likely to create it for the first time or otherwise to reset it; see: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes/#turn-on-kubernetes

Summary:

1. From the Docker Dashboard (Docker Desktop app), select **Settings**.
2. Select **Kubernetes** from the left sidebar.
3. Next to **Enable Kubernetes**, select the checkbox.
4. Select **Apply & Restart** to save the settings and then select Install to confirm.